# Use energy method to prove uniqueness of a parabolic PDE

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, derivatives

A question in my PDE class is

Suppose $a(x) = a_{ij}(x)$ takes values in the class of symmetric, positive definite $n \times n$ matrices, $b(x)$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Consider the PDE

$u_t = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}(x)\left(\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \right) + \sum_{i=1}^n b_{i}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}$

in a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, with intial condition $u=u_0(x)$ at $t=0$ and boundary condition $u=g$ at $\partial \Omega$. Try proving uniqueness by considering the difference of two solutions, then multiply the equation by $u(x,t)p(x)$ and integrate by parts.

So following the instructions, let $u = u_{2} - u_{1}$ for two solutions $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ which gives a homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition.  Now, multiplying by $u$ and integrating gives:

$\int_{\Omega}p(x)uu_t= \frac12 \frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega}p(x)u^2 = \int_{\Omega}p(x)u\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}(x)\left(\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \right) + \int_{\Omega}p(x)u\sum_{i=1}^n b_{i}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}$

Now we need to integrate by parts to show somehow that the right hand side must be negative, which would imply $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega}u^2 dx \leq 0$ and show that $u_{1}=u_{2}$.

I've rewritten this in a more compact form as which I hope is correct:
$\frac12 \frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega}p(x)u^2 = \int_{\Omega}p(x)u<a(x)\nabla u, \nabla u> + \int_{\Omega}p(x)u<b,\nabla u>$

From here I assume I need to use integration by parts, then the divergence theorem, which should reveal an appropriate choice for $p(x)$, but I'm not seeing how to get there.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you get the $\langle a \nabla u,\nabla u\rangle$ term in your last expression?

Comment: It's an error.  It should have been $<a(x)∇,∇u>$.

Comment: but that's not really correct either.

Comment: I think this problem requires that the choice of function p(x) be chosen at the start.

Comment: Do you know anything about $\boldsymbol{b}$, maybe something like $-0.5 \boldsymbol{b} \cdot \nabla  \geq 0 $?